# how to use form validation in ionic 4 or 5 that contain ion-input,ion-select,gender radio button,multiple checkbox,ion date time .?

Tags: angular, ionic4, angular8, ionic5

```
<ion-item>
        <ion-label position="floating">Title</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="text"  formControlName="title" id="input" name="title"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>

<ion-item>
        <ion-label position="floating">Client</ion-label>
        <ion-select (ionChange)="selectClient($event)" formControlName="Select_Client" interface="popover">
          <ion-select-option value="1">Lynko Pvt. Ltd.</ion-select-option>
          <ion-select-option value="4">Letsclick Pvt. Ltd. </ion-select-option>
          <ion-select-option value="5">Wirehead </ion-select-option>
          <ion-select-option value="6">Codeyiizen Software & Services Pvt. Ltd.</ion-select-option>
          <ion-select-option value="7">Mariao Barando</ion-select-option>
<ion-item>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you mean validate if they are empty or not you can use the Validators:

```
this.formName = form.group({
Select_Client : ['', Validators.required],
title: ['', Validators.required]
});
```

and then if you want to check if the form is valid you can write :
`this.formName.valid` =>this will return true if the form is valid

Comment: thank you so much adit for help me. this work for me

Comment: glad it works, do Mark the answer accepted so that in future if some one comes it may help them 